# Can we use MAYDAY or PAN PAN on ground?

Tags: emergency, phraseology

Usually we read, on reports, aircraft reporting urgency or emergency during the flight, while airborne. But, is it correct to use these "words" on ground?

Comment: Real-life example: https://youtu.be/jIt6CDLrPOo?t=1m4s

Comment: Mayday on the ground can also be used to report danger to life somewhere else.  For example, you see an aircraft on fire in the circuit.  There has been no radio call.  Broadcasting a mayday stating what you saw and where is a proper procedure.

Comment: Emergencies can even be declared by non-aircraft, for example if a control tower needs to be evacuated for fire or other emergency.

Comment: http://atccommunication.com/mayday-versus-pan-pan  Give a good summary.  If it's immediate life-threatening, then "Mayday" would be proper on the ground too.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it is correct to use MAYDAY or PAN PAN PAN on the ground.

In recurrent training we are often reminded that in the case of a rejected takeoff in a foreign country it is important to use MAYDAY or PAN PAN PAN on the ground to avoid any confusion due to language difficulties.

It's probably a good idea at any airport as a disabled aircraft on a busy runway could be a major hazard to other aircraft landing and taking off.

Comment: And of course you want emergency services by you as soon as they can in basically all the cases you would need to use those words.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely they are correct to use on the ground if the situation warrants. They are used to express an emergency or urgency, and those can happen on the ground as well as the air. Those conditions are roughly the same: passenger illness requiring medical assistance, an engine fire, unlawful interference, etc.

When you make the call you would report your position as being on the ground, and where you are.

Comment: Another example of when Mayday would be appropriate while on the ground is when you've just crashed into said ground (e.g. runway excursion on takeoff or landing, crashing short of the runway, etc.)

Comment: @reirab - I suspect there wasn't much doubt that "If you crash, you can make a mayday call" :p that's pretty much the definition of an emergency

Comment: @JonStory True, but it is "on the ground," as the question asked. :)

Comment: I'd venture that if you're not on the ground, you probably haven't crashed yet

Comment: @JonStory Unless it was a mid-air collision (in which case you'll likely be on the ground soon.)

Comment: Ah but you said you'd crashed into said ground. Either way, definitely send a Mayday

Comment: [Recent example](http://avherald.com/h?article=49681a52&opt=0): airplane lost directional control during landing rollout.